# Laravel(5.6) eloquent order by last message

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a `User` model which has a reference to `MessageParticipant` model (returns all the message subjects the user participating in)

```
public function messages()
{
 return $this->hasMany(MessageParticipant::class);
}
```

The `MessageParticipant` refers to a `MessageSubject` model (returns the message subject participants belong to)

```
public function message_subject()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(MessageSubject::class);
}
```

The `MessageSubject` model refers to a `Message` model (return all the messages within message subject)

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```

I want to return all the message subjects a user is participating in, ordering according to latest message entry to the message subject. 
Below is what I've tried so far.

```
$messages = $user->messages()->search($search)
                    ->join('messages', 'messages.message_subject_id', '=', 'message_subject.id')
                    ->select('message_subject.*', 'messages.created_at AS latest_message_at')
                    ->orderByDesc('latest_message_at')
                    ->paginate(30);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `BelongsToMany` relationship to get the message subjects directly:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function messageSubjects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MessageSubject::class, 'message_participants');
    }
}
```

Then use it with a modified `withCount()` to get the latest message:

```
$messages = $user->messageSubjects()
    ->withCount(['messages as latest_message' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('max(messages.created_at)'));
    }])
    ->search($search)
    ->orderByDesc('latest_message')
    ->paginate(30);
```